# Switching from Eclipse to IntelliJ: Is there a way to split tool windows?

Tags: intellij-idea

Having used Eclipse for more years than I care to admit, I'm currently trying to get adjusted to IntelliJ 12 but I'm having a hard time with the totally different UI metaphors/concepts.

I'd like to be able to have a window layout like this:

```
+--------+------------------------
|        |                       |
|   (1)  |                       |
|        |                       |
|+-------+     Source editor     |
|        |                       |
|   (2)  |                       |
|        |                       |
+--------+-----------------------+
|                                |
|      Console output etc.       | 
+--------------------------------+
```

With (1) being the "Project" tool window and (2) being the "Structure" tool window. I tried to follow the instructions given at http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/viewing-modes.html but changing the "Split" mode doesn't seem to have any noticeable effect. Clicking on the "Structure" or "Project" toolbar buttons always hides the current tool window and displays the other one.

Comment: Split mode enabled for the Structure tool window [works fine for me](http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/964/6301.png).

Comment: I do not doubt that this feature exists, I just can't figure out how to configure it. Just enabling "Split mode" for either of the windows has no effect, clicking on "Project" still hides "Structure" and vice versa.

Comment: For me it was working prior to 13 release, I think. But now it does not. And also at some point toolbar buttons seize to respond at all - so I have to restart IDEA. To illustrate the point, I've uploaded a short video at youtube: http://youtu.be/3Ze0l_Gr6IY

Btw, splitting toolbar windows located at the bottom is functioning properly.
I am using the latest 13.1 release, windows 7 x64

Comment: @AlexeyDanilov it may be caused by [these options enabled](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/7189/pl5r.png).

Comment: Note to self: "Pinned Mode" and "Docked Mode" should be on for both, and "Split Mode" for the bottom pane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, by some more or less random combination of the "docked" , "pinned" , "view as tab" and "split mode" modifiers I got it to work. I wonder why they didn't simply implement dragging the window where you'd like it to appear...

Comment: To those having the same issue, I got it to work using "pinned" and "docked" on both the project and structure window, "split" for the structure window only, and then clicking the two tabs to toggle the windows until the desired effect is achieved. Whew!

Comment: @Trillian +1, this method still works and saved me from a lot of frustration.

Comment: In the end you have to repeatedly do view -> tool windows -> structure/projects to switch between them, until it detects your changes.

Comment: I agree, but in your answer it would be better to describe the exact steps solving the problem in the quiestion as @Trillian have done, thus not only you needs to know how to solve the problem if you posted this question at this site.

Answer (score 10):

Ok. I worked it all out with googling and https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/viewing-modes.html . It's not obvious at all.

In Setting->Appearance & Behavior->Appearance:
Side-by-side layouts on left and right will control whether left and right side splits are horizontal or vertical - you can also Control-click on the divider to switch.

Widescreen tool window layout switches whether vertical or horizontal toolbars get full height/width: on gives full height to side tool windows and off gives full width to bottom(top?).

Comment: Side-by-side Layouts Is what I had enabled but didn't need, wish i read your answer an hour ago :)

Comment: This answer should have more votes; it's much more helpful than "do random stuff".

Answer (score 2):

I love Intellij IDEA,  but every once in a while there is some glitch like this. Anyway, here is a key point that you need to know from [this writeup](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/viewing-modes.html):

> To be able to see two windows simultaneously, the corresponding
>   windows should belong to different groups, that is, one of the windows
>   should have the split mode off and the other one on

.

My problem was I had split mode ON for both the Project Tool window and the Structure Tool window.  If one tool window has that mode OFF, and the other ON, that will help them show together correctly.  However, this is NOT guaranteed to work, which negatively impacts usability. I have filed a usability enhancement request with our friends at Intellij.  I hope others in my situation will help me vote it up: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144963

Answer (score 0):

Usually setting split on the structure and toggle the windows method that Trillian mentioned above works.

However for the case where it does not, I've had some success with editing the project's .idea/workspace.xml file directly and replacing the lines (with all settings) for id="Project" and id="Structure" from a project that has the window layout I want them into the project that I can't get the layout working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First, set the desired two tool windows to be pinned and docked (not floating, not windowed).

Second, the window to be above, set no split mode, the window below, set to split mode.