# IntelliJ: Is there a way to split tool windows horizontally?

Tags: intellij-idea, layout, intellij-14

In IntelliJ I would like to have "project" and "structure" **tool windows** side by side **horizontally**, not vertically. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution in this question: [Switching from Eclipse to IntelliJ: Is there a way to split tool windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557820/switching-from-eclipse-to-intellij-is-there-a-way-to-split-tool-windows/29396100)

In short, you need to go in to the File -> Settings -> Appearance and Behavior -> Appearance: and check "Side-by-side layout on the left."

Truly a UI failure on IntelliJ's part; that should very obviously be a checkbox on the tool window UI, not a setting!