# Intellij IDEA: creating a pane under the source code

Tags: intellij-idea

Having used Eclipse for more years than I care to admit, I'm currently trying to get adjusted to IntelliJ (2016.2, Community) but I'm having a hard time with the totally different UI metaphors/concepts.

I'd like to be able to have a window layout like this:

```
+--------+------------------------
|        |                       |
|   (1)  |                       |
|        |                       |
|+-------+     Source editor     |
|        |                       |
|   (2)  |                       |
|        |-----------------------+
|        |                       |
|        |  Console output etc.  | 
+--------+-----------------------+
```

Luckily, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557820/switching-from-eclipse-to-intellij-is-there-a-way-to-split-tool-windows) helped me with splitting panes to get (1) and (2).

However, I have not been able to find out how to rearrange tool windows so that I can get a (for example) Terminal tool window that is *directly* underneath the source editor pane, instead of one that looks like this:

```
+--------+------------------------
|        |                       |
|   (1)  |                       |
|        |                       |
|+-------+     Source editor     |
|        |                       |
|   (2)  |                       |
+--------------------------------+
|                                |
|      Console output etc.       | 
+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for this question! I never thought about this. Because of you i tested it and i think this is really nice for big project structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open "Settings" > "Appearance & Behavior" > "Appearance" and enable "Widescreen tool window layout".

Tested in DataGrip and PyCharm. Should be exactly the same in IDEA, Webstorm as far as i know - i used them all and the UI is the same everywhere (and i like that).

Answer (score 0):

You could just float the panels next to your IntelliJ main windows like this screenshot.

[image]

Comment: But then it is no more in the same window, and the op indicates that it should be a "window" layout and not a "multi-window" layout.